# Error updating jars with Eclipse GWT 2.0 plugin

Tags: eclipse, gwt

Ever since updating our project to the newest version of the Eclipse GWT plugin and GWT 2.0 we get an error when starting Eclipse.

This is the error message:

> An internal error occurred during:
>   "Updating project/war/WEB-INF/lib with
>   jars from GWT - 2.0.0".

Here is the exception message:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Attempted to beginRule: R/, does not
>   match outer scope rule: P/project

Everything works just fine, I just get this error when Eclipse starts up. I've done everything I can think of to fix it, but it still happens.

Any ideas? Is anyone else getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

This was seen when, for instance, using a too old version of subclipse (see [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform/msg51857.html), and [bug 129045](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=129045) or [bug 128709](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=128709))

This is linked to a change in the `ISchedulingRule modifyRule(IResource resource)` of the `Resources` component.

So are you using a compatible version of eclipse (**[i.e 3.5x](http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/webtoolkit/usingeclipse.html)**) with GWT2.0?

Comment: Yeah, we are using the latest version of SpringSource Tool Suite, which is based on Eclipse 3.5.1.